# How to close a popup alert which may appear any time while browsing the website in cypress?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

While browsing the website an email popup alert may appear , how can I close it **whenever** it appears (the problem I don't know when it may appear)

```
if (cy.get('.popup').isDisplayed) {
  cy.get('.popup a').click() // Close button
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To close **whenever** requires some sort of watcher, which doesn't quite fit the Cypress pattern.

Best approach would be to `cy.stub()` it so it never occurs. What type of popup do you have, what triggers it?

If it's timer based, you might be able to `cy.clock()` to freeze the clock. If you need to `cy.tick(milliseconds)` during the test, then follow it immediately with

```js
if (Cypress.$('.popup').length) {  // non-failing check if popup is present
  cy.get('.popup a').click()
}
```